# How to have an optional character field in a django form, but validate it so that an empty string is not allowed?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a form for a PATCH request similar to the following:

```
class SampleForm(Form):
    optional_field = CharField(required=False, validators=[optional_text_field_validator])
```

This is the validator-

```
def optional_text_field_validator(text):
    if len(text) == 0:
        raise ValidationError("This field cannot be empty")
```

I have also tried-

```
def optional_text_field_validator(text):
    if text == 0:
        raise ValidationError("This field cannot be empty")
```

I am doing this so that it is not mandatory to include the `optional_field` in a request, but when it is present, it's value cannot be an empty string. However, the form validation is passing with both the above approaches (`is_valid` returns `True`), when it should be failing.

How do I implement this?

Comment: It's "validators", not "validator"

Comment: Hey, validator was a typo, I corrected it in the post. In my code it is  `validators`, but the issue still exists.

Comment: Does it stops if you put breakpoint inside and run debugger?